# How to use the --verbose flag in the MySQL 5.6 command line client?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

Going by the list of flags [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_mysql_Command-Line_Tool), with the line at the top about usage: `Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]`.

I am running Windows 8; my table is "contact"; I want to create a tee file for `source C:/myfile.sql` with the verbose option on.

I have tried `mysql -v contact`, `-v contact`, `--verbose contact`, `--verbose source C:/myfile.sql`, and various others.

EDIT: [adding screenshot of where I'm trying to run this, in case it helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu5MF.png)

Comment: Your db name is **contacts** but you are putting **contact** to mysql client..

Comment: Bad typo -- the table name is indeed "contact", my apologies.

Comment: @Rohawk and which is your database name?

Comment: so what error do u see ?

Comment: Ah crap, the DATABASE name is contact.  The table itself is contactlist, if that ends up also being relevant.  I need more coffee.

Comment: "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -v contact' at line 1".  The docs online basically just repeated another iteration of the list of flags.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The correct syntax for a verbose interactive session is:

```
c:\> mysql -u yourUser -p -v yourDatabase
```

This will launch an interactive session (prompting you for password), and set `yourDatabase` as the default database for the session.

Once in this interactive session, issue a `tee` command:

```
mysql> tee c:/temp/my.out
```

And now you can source your script:

```
mysql> source c:/myfile.sql
```

Of course, you can avoid all this pain by simply putting this in your command prompt:

```
c:\> mysql -u yourUser -pYourPassword -v yourDatabase < myfile.sql > my.out
```

This will:

1. Push the contents of `myfile.sql` to an "interactive" mysql session... that's essentially a batch process
2. Redirect all contents of the batch process to `my.out`

---

Reference:

- [MySQL Reference Manual: `mysql` CLI: `mysql` options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html)

Answer (score 1):

That should work, be aware of the db name.

```
mysql -v contact
```

If you db requires login:

```
mysql -v -udbuser -p contact
```