# How to turn "--Verbose" option on in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

When I start mySQL command line client, I am prompted to enter my password. After doing so, I want to know what the proper command would be to turn on the "--verbose" option.

Comment: Um... how about `mysql --verbose` ?

Comment: that brings up an error, after I enter my password in in the command line client, and type "--verbose" it just tells me I have a syntax error.

Comment: No.  Use this: `mysql -u yourUser -p --verbose yourDatabase`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the --verbose flag in the MySQL 5.6 command line client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959112/how-to-use-the-verbose-flag-in-the-mysql-5-6-command-line-client)

Answer (score 2):

mysql -u user -p -v

or

mysql -u user -p -vvv (more verbose)

Comment: While this might be a awesome solution to the problem, please consider adding some clarification on why this is a good answer and what it does.